# How do I get out of a type? JSON Parsing with Data.Aeson

Tags: haskell

Haskell beginner here. I want to pass a "type" parameter with JSON, and have it parse into a native Haskell type using read. The following works:

```
data CreatureType = Bot | Player deriving (Generic, Typeable, Show, Read)
data Creature = Creature CreatureType deriving (Typeable, Show)

instance FromJSON Creature where
    parseJSON (A.Object v) = Creature <$> read <$> (v .: "type")  
    parseJSON _          = mzero
```

I want to change it to work with `readMay`, so that it doesn't crash if read fails. I keep getting stuck. parseJSON needs to return `mzero` if `readMay` returns `Nothing`.

Main Question: How can I get this function to use `readMay` to return `mzero` on a failure with read?

Here's what I've tried:

```
instance FromJSON Creature where
    parseJSON (A.Object v) = do
        let t = (v .: "type") :: Parser String
            mt = readMay <$> t :: Parser (Maybe CreatureType)
        -- ?? 
        -- guard -- I can't use this because it wants a Bool, and I only have Parser Bool
        -- Creature <$> read <$> mt
    parseJSON _          = mzero
```

`mt` is `Parser (Maybe CreatureType)`. How can I change what I return if it is `Nothing`? I can't use pattern matching, because `Data.Aeson` doesn't seem to export a value constructor for Parser. I can't seem to find any methods that will give me the value inside a parser, so, is there a generic haskell method that does it? I've looked at `Control.Applicative` and can't find anything. Here are the docs for `Data.Aeson`. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't binding the value in the do-block work?

```
maybeCreature <- mt
case maybeCreature of
  Nothing -> mzero
  Just cr -> return (Creature cr)
```

or similar?

```
instance FromJSON Creature where
    parseJSON (A.Object v) = do
        let t = (v .: "type") :: Parser String
            mt = readMay <$> t :: Parser (Maybe CreatureType)
        maybeCreature <- mt
        -- variant 1, guard
        guard (isJust maybeCreature)
        return (Creature $ fromJust maybeCreature)
        -- variant 2, fromMaybe
        fromMaybe mzero (return . Creature) maybeCreature
        -- variant 3, case, see above
    parseJSON _          = mzero
```

Comment: Yes, it works |sigh|, you can do it all in one line: `mt <- readMay <$> (v .: "type")`. I did think of that, and tried it. Something else must have been wrong. Such is the life of the Haskell beginner :) Thanks.

Comment: Probably a forgotten parenthesis or something when you tried before. Some little thing with big consequences. :-/ That doesn't stop with experience, but it gets rarer.

Comment: I'm curios as to why `v .:? "type" .!= mzero` is not adequate.

Comment: Also why is it necessary to call read and not declare and instance of FromJSON on CreatureType. Perhaps there is some key element that I am missing here.

Comment: 1st question - because I need to return mzero if there is no type matching the value, not if there is not type at all. You're probably right about the 2nd.